# If I create a file named -t in Unix, how can I list it with ls?

Tags: unix, ls

The problem is taken from 'Unix programming environment by Brian Kernighan and Rob Pike'I tried with grep but to no avail. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `ls -- -t` would work.

Comment: standard trick for most gnu utils `--` as a command line argument tells the app that there are no further command line options after that point, and `-` will lose its special meaning. `foo -arg1 -arg2 -- -not_an_arg`

Comment: This is very helpful. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for taking the time to answer my query.

Comment: You can also use `ls ./-t`, though that will affect the way the file name is displayed.